# scheduling own processes C/linux

Tags: c, linux

I am writing some application on embedded linux, which starts few processes. Each process starts external binary once a time.
The question is, what is the simplest way to set priorities for those processes? Should I use the `sched_setparam` function?

Comment: This might be better asked on superuser.com - stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using [setpriority](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) could be enough?